# Why does 'new' fail in class initialization

Tags: c++

win7
gcc 6.4.0
cygwin 2.9.0

the following code fails in function g_block during class initialization but not when used in main. The failure is in the 'for' loop when I attempt to initialize the code (initialization is a side issue here). In both cases allocation seems successful but when used in a class, I can't use the memory allocated.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

   typedef struct {                // gsl allocation 'block' descritpoin
      size_t size;                 // block bytes size
      double* data;                // pointer to the first byte of the block
   } gsl_block;

   typedef struct {                // matrix definition 
      size_t size1;                // number of rows
      size_t size2;                // number of columns
      size_t tda;                  // number of elements in row (stride between rows)
      double* data;                // pointer to matrix[0][0]
      gsl_block* block;            // pointer to the gsl_matrix block
      int owner;                   // 1: deallocation permitted
   } gsl_matrix;

class X {
public:
    inline static gsl_matrix& g_matrix(size_t row, size_t col) 
                         {return g_matrix(row, col, g_block(row * col));};

   static gsl_block&  g_block(size_t size)  {
      double* ptr = new double(size);
      cout << "size " << setw(5)<< size << " addr range " 
           << hex << setfill('0') << ptr << " - "  << (ptr + size*sizeof(double))
           << dec << setfill(' ') << endl;
      for(size_t ndx = 0; ndx < size; ndx++) ptr[ndx] = 0.0;
      return * new gsl_block{size, ptr};
   }; 

   static gsl_matrix& g_matrix(size_t row, size_t col, gsl_block& block) {
      return * new gsl_matrix{row, col, col, block.data, &block, 0}; }

   gsl_matrix& g_mat;
   X() : g_mat(g_matrix(92, 92)) {}
}; // class X
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   gsl_matrix& mat = X::g_matrix(92, 92);
   X* x = new X();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be overusing `new`. This looks like Java code translated to c++. For example, you can simply return `gsl_block` directly from `g_block`. No need for a reference and no need for dynamic allocation. And you never seem to `delete` anything you allocate. It's *very* unintuitive to have to `delete` an object returned by reference.

Comment: The `g_matrix` function may compile with your compiler due to a **language extension**, but binding an rvalue to a reference to non-`const` is not valid standard C++. If it does compile then you're returning a reference to a now again non-existent temporary, called a **dangling reference**. That's Undefined Behavior, on top of the language extension.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf All of the function return non-const references, either given from another function or returning `*new T`. Though the design looks broken, I don't see any dangling references.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Not the first `g_matrix` overload.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's not a dangling reference. It's returning the result of `g_matrix(row, col, g_block(row * col));` which itself is a reference.

Comment: Oh, my eyes. Thanks.

Comment: `return * new gsl_block{size, ptr};` is highly non idiomatic c++ code. Modern idiomatic c++ code would return a shared_ptr, older code would simply return the pointer

Comment: @pm100 It looks like `unique_ptr` is good enough in this case.

Comment: In C++, you use square brackets for array indices. Your line `double* ptr = new double(size);` puts `size` in parentheses, which makes it used for initializing the new double. Thus, `ptr` is a pointer to a single `double` with the value `size`.

Comment: `ptr + size*sizeof(double)` forms an out of bounds pointer

Comment: Although as others are pointing out, this isn’t good code anyway. Look into using `std::vector`.

Comment: @M.M Except for the part where `size` isn’t actually the number of `double`s allocated, it’s a pointer to one-past-the-end, which isn’t dereferenceable; since it’s just being printed, that isn’t a problem.

Comment: @DanielH it is a lot more than one past the end, that is my point

Comment: @ Daniel H I am trying to allocation a block of memory of the given size.   I am using the Gnu Scientific Library (gsl), I follow the gsl rules and they mandate a block of memory for a matrix.  I seem to be allocating a single instance of type double and initializing that reference with 'size' (new double (intializer))..Looking at cplusplus.com (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) and using  double* ptr = (double*)::operator new (size); also fails.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez A `std::vector` is also a single block which you can access with the `data()` member function. You almost never want to call `operator new` directly (and definitely not in this case), and when you do, that’s not how you do it. Note that, confusingly, `operator new` is different from just regular `new`. Regular `new` is what you usually want if you insist on doing memory management yourself.

Comment: `typedef struct` ; are you writing C or C++? If C++ then that's just pointless noise.

Comment: `using namespace std;` hmmm. Ok, as long as you don't put that in a header file..

Comment: To all. I am using the Gnu Scientific Library (gsl) which is a"C" implementation. I am bound by what they mandate. thank you on pointing out that <vector> allows access to the data block used. I emphasis that the code is an example to illustrate the problem and not production code. The use of ''struct'. comes from gsl/gsl_block_double.h. As to qualitative issues, my code, my quality. As to advise, always welcome and mostly followed. As to references, I like them. They say something about humanity. I am reading all of your comments. thanks all

Answer (score 2):

```
double* ptr = new double(size);
```

This line creates a single `double` with the value `size` on the free store, and returns a pointer to it.

```
for(size_t ndx = 0; ndx < size; ndx++) ptr[ndx] = 0.0;
```

This line then invokes undefined behavior by attempting to write to memory that your program does not own.

You should really use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.  As your program stands, you have a significant potential to leak memory.  If you made `gsl_block::data` a `std::vector<double>`, your classes would get proper copy and move semantics for free, and you wouldn't need to directly use `new` anywhere in your code.

EDIT:
Now that you've mentioned you're using GNU Scientific Library, you should probably just use the functions that library provides for allocating and freeing matricies: `gsl_matrix_alloc` and `gsl_matrix_free`.  I would re-write your `X` class to just contain a `std::unique_ptr` with `gsl_matrix_free` as its deleter:

```
struct X
{
    struct free_matrix
    {
        void operator()(gsl_matrix* mat)
        {
            gsl_matrix_free(mat);
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<gsl_matrix, free_matrix> g_mat;

    X(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
        : g_mat(gsl_matrix_alloc(rows, cols))
    {}
};
```

You could even go further and completely wrap `gsl_matrix` in a more C++-like interface, with member functions that call `gsl_matrix_get`/`gsl_matrix_set` or `gsl_matrix_pointer` to provide simple access to the matrix elements.

Comment: I can not use <vector>. I am using a package (Gnu Scientific Library) which defines my usage. I changed the ptr to double * ptr = (double*) ::operator new (sizeof(double)*size) which cplusplus.com seems to work. thanks all.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Edited.  Just use the functions GSL provides: `gsl_matrix_alloc` (or `gsl_matrix_calloc` if you want the matrix initially filled with 0s) and `gsl_matrix_free`.  If you _must_ do it yourself, `double* ptr = new double[size];` is the correct syntax, not that monstrosity that cplusplus.com gave you.

Comment: thanks for the code. Since I need to initialize the allocated block of code and I don't know haw, or what, gsl alloc/dete functions do I decided to roll my own. Not clever, but it would have been expedient if it worked. On the other hand I've learned quite a bit just by asking the question.. Ithanks

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html#matrix-allocation) for more info.  Rolling your own is never faster or easier than using library-provided functions.